# Why is Selenium overriding my firefox profile

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, nuitka

I am making python selenium script to automate some google search with firefox.

I am using python 3.7 on Windows 10 64b.

Something weird happened. When I run my python script, it’is fine.
When I compile it with Nuitka and I run the exe, Firefox is opening with some proxy added (127.0.01:53445).

So I added this line:

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 0)

And again, the script run fine but when I compile it, the exe opens Firefox with a proxy.

It is a pain as this 127.0.01 proxy creates an issue to open google and my program is broken.

Does anyone already faced this weird behaviour of selenium?

Comment: You could skip Nuika and run your selenium script from the command line.

Comment: No, I couldn’t as I need absolutely to compile it for distribution

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what code you are using relevant to `webdriver` I am mostly guessing here. I would suggest rotating the proxy as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

def proxy_generator():
  # REQUIRED - pip install html5lib
  response = requests.get("https://sslproxies.org/")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
  proxy = {'https': choice(list(map(lambda x: x[0] + ':' + x[1], list(zip(map(lambda x: x.text, soup.findAll('td')[::8]), map(lambda x: x.text, soup.findAll('td')[1::8]))))))}
  return proxy

PROXY = proxy_generator()# Commented out proxy option "58.216.202.149:8118"

firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don’t want any proxy. I need to deactivate proxy. That is why I added the proxy type 0.

Comment: @Gauthier Buttez but if this works after compiling in Nuitka, you are one step closer.

Comment: Thanks @Jortega for trying to help, but google doesn’t like proxy. I need to avoid proxies.